# FODY - Duplicate type with name 'ProcessedByFody' in assembly

Tags: fody

I haven't figured out the exact duplication steps but I'm frequently getting this at runtime.

A full rebuild fixes things.

An unhandled exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in Unknown Module.
Additional information: Duplicate type with name 'ProcessedByFody' in assembly ...

People seem to be having similar issues after switching branches.

Comment: can u try fody 5.0.3

Comment: Thanks very much!  I will give it a try. :)

Comment: I might not be able to test it any time soon.  Got:  
1>C:\Development\Source\DotNet\packages\Fody.5.0.3\build\Fody.targets(38,5): error : Fody is only supported on MSBuild 16 and above. Current version: 15.
I think that means I'd need visual studio 2019?  We are mostly on 2017 at work.

Comment: yep that correct https://github.com/Fody/Fody/issues/679